# Why predict in mlr does not work when there are fewer observations used for prediction than training?

Tags: r, lm, predict

I am trying to use multiple linear regression in R, and I have trained my data by loading it from a file. But when I try to predict, I get a warning message:

```
"Warning messages:
1: 'newdata' had 45 rows but variables found have 8676 rows
2: In predict.lm(reg, tin) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading"
```

My code is simple :

```
yval = read.table("value_of_y.txt",header = T)
xval = read.table("Rmat.txt",header = T)
reg<-lm(yval$y~xval$x1+xval$x2+xval$x3+xval$x4+xval$x5+xval$x6+xval$x7+xval$x8+xval$x9+xval$x10+xval$x11+xval$x12+xval$x13+xval$x14)
summary(reg)
tin = read.table("Rtest.txt",header = T)
predict(reg,tin)
```

My training data (Rmat.txt):

> x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 
>   1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
>   1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

(value_of_y.txt): 
5 
-5 
5 
5 
-5 
5 
5 
-5 
-5

My testing data which I use for prediction (Rtest.txt)

> x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 
>   -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 
>   -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 
>   -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 
>   -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1

How should I use the predict function instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more careful when using the formula syntax with `lm` and predict. The column names in the model and the new data.frame must match exactly and this is not possible when you use the "$" syntax in the formula. Try something like

```
yval = read.table("value_of_y.txt",header = T)
xval = read.table("Rmat.txt",header = T)
reg<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+x11+x12+x13+x14, cbind(yval, xval))
summary(reg)
tin = read.table("Rtest.txt",header = T)
predict(reg,tin)
```

Comment: I tried it, it still gives a warning "Warning message:
In predict.lm(reg, tin) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading"

Comment: That sounds like it may be a problem with your data. Since you have not yet made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) however, it's impossible to tell for sure.

Comment: I have added some sample training and testing data

Comment: Well, your sample data doesn't nearly have enough observations to estimate 14 parameters. Perhaps you can reduce the variables in your example. Just make sure you can actually run it. Use `dput()`s of your data as described in the link on how to wrote a reproducible example. Is all your real data that discrete?

Comment: Yes, am working with discrete data, I have around 8000 observations for those 14 parameters, is that not enough? Do you think the problem is due to discrete values?